# Pasar model de una vista a otra MVC C# .NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, mvc

tengo una consulta que llevo rato tratando de resolver pero no lo he logrado, tengo una vista con razor en un proyecto ASP.NET que usa MVC, en cuestión la vista es un carrito de compras, cada ítem (producto) se puede marcar o desmarcar con un checkbox:

```
 <td rowspan="2"
     style="vertical-align: top; padding-top: 20px; text-align: center;">
     <input type="checkbox" name="" id="chkbx" class="form-control-cart checksItems" data-parent-id="@item.ShoppingCartItemId"
            onclick="updateItemStyle(this, '@item.ShoppingCartItemId')"><br>
     <i id="form-control2" class="fa-solid fa-trash fa-2xl btnClose" data-id="@item.ShoppingCartItemId">&nbsp;</i>
 </td>
```

como no puedo modificar la tabla en la base de datos para excluir los ítems desmarcados agregue propiedades a los ítems para saber cuales están desmarcados, llegan a un método en un controlador que los toma y filtra cuales tienen la propiedad en true y cuales en false

```
public async Task<ActionResult> SendItems(List<ViewShoppingCartItems> items)
{
    List<ViewShoppingCartItems> productos = items.Where(cartItem => cartItem.Check).ToList();
    foreach (ViewShoppingCartItems producto in productos)
    {
        producto.stores.RemoveAll(response => !response.isChecked);
    }
    ShoppingCartViewModel model = new ShoppingCartViewModel
    {
        CartItems = productos,
        CartCount = productos.Count
    };
    return View("~/Views/SaleConfirmation/SaleConfirmationDesktop.cshtml", model);
}
```

hasta ahí todo bien hago eso para filtrar el carrito, por así decirlo, que pase a una ventana de confirmación y que se cree el pedido, ahora el detalle es que tengo la función para enviar los ítems con Ajax:

```
function SendShoppingCartItems() {
    var dataItemsAndStores = GetProductsAndStores();
    console.log(dataItemsAndStores);
    window.$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("SendItems", "SaleConfirmation")",
        data: JSON.stringify({ items: dataItemsAndStores }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

esa función esta anclada a un botón:

```
<button type="button" class="btn-cart-save" onclick="SendShoppingCartItems()">Enviar pedido</button>
```

el funcionamiento que necesito es que se ejecute esa función, obtenga los ítems, los envié al método, se filtren(hasta acá bien) y se envié a la nueva vista, con esto me refiero a que se redireccione a esa vista con los ítems que se filtraron, lo que hace ahora es enviarlos, filtrarlos pero no redirecciona, se queda en la misma vista.

Les agradezco su ayuda y feliz año 2024!

Comment: Ajax se usa para obtener/guardar datos sin recargar la pagina. ¿Por qué usas ajax si vas a hacer una redirección, la cual si o si te va a recargar la página?

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con lo que dice Yussef, podria agregar que le envies desde el controlador y asi envies por parametro el objeto, saludos.